# Ggplot Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, as.date

I am using Ggplot in a for loop to draw five different time-series plots with two lines in each plot.

I have written the following code (sorry for the long code):

```
country_names <- c("Norway", "Spain", "India", "Australia", "United states")
M <- length(country_names)

for (m in 1:M){
  print(ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(gdp_cntrs[[m]][13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])]), 
       aes(x = as.Date(as.yearqtr(time(gdp_cntrs[[m]]))[13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])]), 
       y = gdp_cntrs[[m]][13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])], colour = "GDP %")) +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(forcasts_ar[[m]]), aes(x = 
      as.Date(as.yearqtr(time(gdp_cntrs[[m]]))[13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])]), 
      y = forcasts_ar[[m]], colour = "AR-1 model")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "black")) +
  ylab("Changes %") +
  ggtitle(paste("AR-1 model in", country_names[m])) +
  labs(y = "Changes %",
       x = "Time",
       colour = "Series:") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = c(1.15, 0.6)) + 
  scale_x_yearmon(format="%Y-%m", n=6)  +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "cm")))
}
```

However, when I use `scale_x_yearmon(format="%Y-%m", n=6)`
I get the following Error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Without `scale_x_yearmon(format="%Y-%m", n=6)` the code runs smoothly.

I do not understand this error because the aes(x = ) is clearly a date variable.
For clarification (I have checked this for every m):

```
> for (m in 1:M){
 x <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(time(gdp_cntrs[[m]]))[13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])])
 str(x)
 }
 Date[1:59], format: "2007-01-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-07-01" "2007-10-01" "2008-01-01" ...
 Date[1:59], format: "2007-01-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-07-01" "2007-10-01" "2008-01-01" ...
 Date[1:59], format: "2007-01-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-07-01" "2007-10-01" "2008-01-01" ...
 Date[1:59], format: "2007-01-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-07-01" "2007-10-01" "2008-01-01" ...
 Date[1:59], format: "2007-01-01" "2007-04-01" "2007-07-01" "2007-10-01" "2008-01-01"
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this, please?

Comment: Please, define `gdp_cntrs` and `forcasts_ar`. Thanks.

Comment: > str(gdp_cntrs[[1]])
Time-Series [1:71, 1] from 2004 to 2022: 1.3 0.9 1.1 1.5 1 -1.2 1.4 0.3 2.5 0.2 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : NULL
..$ : chr "...1" 

````
> str(forecasts_ar[[1]])
num [1:59] 0.908 0.53 0.77 1.046 0.947 ...
So, gdp_cntr is a list of time-series and forecasts are numeric

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if one uses `as.yearmon()` instead of `as.Date()` the Error does not appear and loop will print plots with `scale_x_yearmon(format="%Y-%m", n=6)` option enabled.

So, my solution was to replace `as.Date()` with `as.yearmon()`

```
for (m in 1:M){
  print(ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(gdp_cntrs[[m]][13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])]), 
       aes(x = as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(time(gdp_cntrs[[m]]))[13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])]), 
       y = gdp_cntrs[[m]][13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])], colour = "GDP %")) +
  geom_line(data = as.data.frame(forcasts_ar[[m]]), aes(x = 
      as.yearmon(as.yearqtr(time(gdp_cntrs[[m]]))[13:length(gdp_cntrs[[m]])]), 
      y = forcasts_ar[[m]], colour = "AR-1 model")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "black")) +
  ylab("Changes %") +
  ggtitle(paste("AR-1 model in", country_names[m])) +
  labs(y = "Changes %",
       x = "Time",
       colour = "Series:") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = c(1.15, 0.6)) + 
  scale_x_yearmon(format="%Y-%m", n=6)  +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "cm")))
}
```